# How to get latest records if date is in YYYY-MM-DD and time in hh:mm:ss AM/PM format

Tags: mysql

I want to get the latest records in my database which has fields date and time as varchar and in the format (YYYY-MM-DD and time in hh:mm:ss AM/PM format) .I need
to figure out a way to sort them.

on executing this query:

```
SELECT editdate,edittime from history where taskid like '%.433' ORDER BY editdate DESC ,STR_TO_DATE(edittime,'%H:%i:%s') DESC ;
```

I am getting the output

```
+------------+-------------+
| editdate   | edittime    |
+------------+-------------+
| 2017-08-22 | 12:53:36 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 12:52:23 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 12:50:42 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 12:39:38 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 12:37:13 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 12:29:33 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 02:52:44 PM |
| 2017-08-22 | 02:50:35 PM |
+------------+-------------+
```

But i want 2 PM above 12 PM for record to be latest.

Please help!!

Comment: Store dates and times as single entities and using a correct data type. Then get back to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT editdate,edittime from history where taskid like '%.433' ORDER BY editdate DESC ,STR_TO_DATE(edittime,'%h:%i:%s%p') DESC ;`

Try above query.

[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9e1a6/1)

As your time field is in format of **`'%h:%i:%s%p'`** you need to add ***`%p`*** for **AM and PM**

Comment: Nothing's changed

Comment: I changed from %H to %h and applied samething that you said and it worked.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to

```
SELECT editdate,edittime from history where taskid like '%.433' ORDER BY editdate DESC ,STR_TO_DATE(edittime,'%H:%i:%s') ASC;
```

Notice the ASC at the very end. This means it will order the times ascend, so smallest date first.